# Sonata DateTimePickerType class default date displays wrong date time format

Tags: php, symfony, datetimepicker, sonata

I got stuck.I can't figure out how to correctly set up default date and time using sonata DateTimePickerType class. I've tried different ways, but none of them has not been helpful so far. In the screenshots below the **"help"** key displays the right date and time, but when I use **"dp_defaul_date"** things break down. Moreover, **the date and time** are from the same **object instance**. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

[image: Code snipet]

[image: Formatted dates and times]

Answer (score 1):

You can give the `DateTimePickerType` a format like so:

```
->add('myDate', DateTimePickerType::class, [
    'format' => 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm',
]);
```

Change the format to your desired format and it should render like that.

Comment: MylesK, thanks for your answer. I've already tried that. Using "format" removes the "dp_default_date" default value. That is to say, this displays empty string.

Answer (score 1):

For people who may come across the same problem, after hours trying, this is how I got it right:

```
$formMapper
->add('dateOfAdoption', 'sonata_type_datetime_picker',
     [
        'dp_default_date' => $container->getCreatedAt()->format('d M. Y H:i '),
        'datepicker_use_button' => true,
        'mapped' => false,
     ]
);

Note: 
d - The day of the month (from 01 to 31)
M - A short textual representation of a month (three letters)
Y - A four digit representation of a year
H - 24-hour format of an hour (00 to 23)
i - Minutes with leading zeros (00 to 59)
```