# "Enabled from" on a new Sonata Page Bundle site is invalid

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, sonata

I have a brand-new installation of Sonata Page Bundle. I am creating a Site entity using the Site admin screen.

I use the DateTimePicker that comes with the bundle to choose the "enabled from" date. The picker creates this date: `May 27, 2021, 6:40:43 pm`

I then save the page. The validator tells me that "This value is not valid." On a string that the same page's picker generated!

**Is this a known bug? Or am I doing something wrong?** I would just leave this blank, but the field is mandatory.

For reference, composer says I have page-bundle version 3.22.2, which packagist says is the newest stable version. The version for admin-bundle is 3.100.2.

Also for reference: My Firefox browser is set to use American English as its language, in case that's relevant.

Answer (score 1):

I installed a symfony (v4.4.25) + sonata project with PHP 7.4.2 to reproduce this and I didn't have this error, my browser is in english too.

[image]

[image]

You should verify if you have moment.min.js or any javascript missing. The javascript should change the date format to a database friendly format, mysql for me, on submit event.

[image]

After installing the sonata bundles with the recipes (to avoid doing all the configuration manually), I added to sonata_admin.yaml

```
   assets:
        extra_javascripts:
            - bundles/sonatapage/sonata-page.back.min.js
        extra_stylesheets:
            - bundles/sonatapage/sonata-page.back.min.css
```

I had the following error on /admin/app/sonatapagesite/1/edit

```
Too few arguments to function Sonata\Form\Type\BasePickerType::__construct(), 0 passed in /Users/hyper/Work/Stackoverflow/so/vendor/symfony/form/FormRegistry.php on line 91 and exactly 3 expected
```

To fix it, I added to bundles.php

```
Sonata\Form\Bridge\Symfony\SonataFormBundle::class => ['all' => true],
```

Comment: Hey HypeR, thanks for your detailed answer and the insightful comment about missing JavaScript files. I noticed I was missing sonata-page.back.min.js, so I ran assets:install, and while that got rid of the missing script error, it didn't fix the problem :-(. 

I looked at Firefox's network inspector panel, and it looks like the JavaScript -- now included correctly -- is not converting the date format before the POST is sent. For example, this is what shows up in the request headers: s60b7cfa5c4938[enabledFrom] "Jun+3,+2021,+8:39:22+pm"

Comment: My request headers shows the same format as yours, the error is not javascript based.


Check symfony requirements https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup.html#technical-requirements, maybe you have a problem with intl extension.
Also check if you have a locale set in config/translation.yaml


I found that the error "This is value is not valid" for this particular field is thrown in the method "reverseTransform" of vendor/symfony/form/Extension/Core/DataTransformer/DateTimeToLocalizedStringTransformer.php 


Look for the TransformationFailedException around line 152 and add some debug

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the validator is doing something wrong, as it expects a different format (probably yyyy-mm-dd).

I found an answer made by @Capfer to a similar question that may be useful. He basically changes the expected date format of the form type.

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57003437/sonata-datetimepickertype-class-default-date-displays-wrong-date-time-format)

```
$formMapper
->add('dateOfAdoption', 'sonata_type_datetime_picker',
     [
        'dp_default_date' => $container->getCreatedAt()->format('d M. Y H:i '),
        'datepicker_use_button' => true,
        'mapped' => false,
     ]
);

Note: 
d - The day of the month (from 01 to 31)
M - A short textual representation of a month (three letters)
Y - A four digit representation of a year
H - 24-hour format of an hour (00 to 23)
i - Minutes with leading zeros (00 to 59)
```

Comment: So I guess I use ez-extends to extend the bundle, then override the form type? OK. If if I don't see a simpler solution in the next few days, I'll mark your answer as the correct one and award the bounty. Thanks for writing it.